# Write to word tablecell with Java, Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

I have word document with a table. I want to insert text in those cells using Java and I have added Apache POI to my project.

However, I have only succeeded to read from the document. My application gets all cells in the table. But I don't know how to insert new text in each cell? Any ideas?

```
  String SOURCE_FILE = "template.doc";

    DocumentProcessor instance = new DocumentProcessor();
    HWPFDocument doc = null;
    try {
        doc = instance.openDocument(SOURCE_FILE);

        Range range = doc.getRange();
        TableIterator itr = new TableIterator(range);
        while(itr.hasNext()) {
            Table table = itr.next();
            for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < table.numRows(); rowIndex++) {
                TableRow row = table.getRow(rowIndex);
                for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < row.numCells(); colIndex++) {
                    TableCell cell = row.getCell(colIndex);
                    cell.getParagraph(0).text().replace("", "Hello");
                    System.out.println(cell.getParagraph(0).text());
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        saveDocument(doc, SOURCE_FILE);

    }
}


private HWPFDocument openDocument(String file) throws Exception {
    URL res = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(file);
    HWPFDocument document = null;
    if (res != null) {
        document = new HWPFDocument(new POIFSFileSystem(
                new File(res.getPath())));
    }
    return document;
}

private static void saveDocument(HWPFDocument doc, String file) {
    try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
        doc.write(out);
        doc.close();
        System.out.println("File saved");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  public class TableCreate{

 public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {

    //Blank Document
    XWPFDocument document= new XWPFDocument();

   //Write the Document in file system
   FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(
   new File("create_table.docx"));

   //create table
   XWPFTable table = document.createTable();
  //create first row
  XWPFTableRow tableRowOne = table.getRow(0);
  tableRowOne.getCell(0).setText("col one, row one");
  tableRowOne.addNewTableCell().setText("col two, row one");
  tableRowOne.addNewTableCell().setText("col three, row one");
  //create second row
  XWPFTableRow tableRowTwo = table.createRow();
  tableRowTwo.getCell(0).setText("col one, row two");
  tableRowTwo.getCell(1).setText("col two, row two");
  tableRowTwo.getCell(2).setText("col three, row two");
  //create third row
  XWPFTableRow tableRowThree = table.createRow();
  tableRowThree.getCell(0).setText("col one, row three");
  tableRowThree.getCell(1).setText("col two, row three");
  tableRowThree.getCell(2).setText("col three, row three");

   document.write(out);
   out.close();
    System.out.println("create_table.docx written successully");
   }
}
```

**Output**

[image]